# ASP.NET: Can I somehow change the HTML rendered by NumericPagerField?

Tags: asp.net

I need to change the HTML rendered by the NumericPagerField. I can't use Control Adapters since NumericPagerField doesn't inherit from System.Web.UI.Control.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the **CreateDataPagers** method. This is the method used to create the actual controls that render the pager. I don't think you can change the container, but it should just be a DIV anyway.

Comment: I created my own Control which inherits NumericPagerField and then i overrided the CreateDataPagers method. I had to reflect the NumericPagerField class and copy a few methods to my class to modify the HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ControlAdapter with the DataPager control where you use the NumericPagerField.