# DataPager with <a> on current page number instead of Label

Tags: asp.net

I have a DataPager working fine except for one thing: the current page number is rendered with a Label and I need it to be as innertext for an `<a>` tag.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you want to use current page number as a link ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to subclass `DataPager` and override `Render`.

EDIT: Better yet, use a [WebControlAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adapters.webcontroladapter.aspx).

> Customizes rendering for the Web control to which the control adapter
>   is attached, to modify the default markup or behavior for specific
>   browsers.

EDIT: Also please see [ASP.NET: Can I somehow change the HTML rendered by NumericPagerField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650708/asp-net-can-i-somehow-change-the-html-rendered-by-numericpagerfield).

Comment: I went for something like yong's solution on your second link! Created a class that inherits from NumericPager and created my own CreateDataPagersForCommand method for CreateDataPagers to call. In the meanwhile I had to remake some methods that are used in this class and are private on NumericPagerField class.